# How to add pre-calculated error bars to bar graph in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'd like to use openpyxl to make a bar graph by referencing pre-calculated averages as the main bars and pre-calculated standard deviations as error bars. each main bar would represent a certain plant mutant grown on a certain treatment type.

Example Data:

```
                         Average    StDev
Mutant1       Treatment1    3        0.5
Mutant1       Treatment1    5        0.4
Mutant2       Treatment2    4        0.8
Mutant2       Treatment2    2        0.1
Mutant3       Treatment3    7        0.4
Mutant3       Treatment3    5        0.7
```

Expertly cropped example graph:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/la6V3.jpg

I've seen other people ask very similar questions but I can't figure out how to understand the error bar part at all.

This is what I have so far. It outputs a graph that's missing a lot of core components so it's pretty bare so far.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Series, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.series_factory import SeriesFactory
from openpyxl.chart.error_bar import ErrorBars
from openpyxl.chart.data_source import NumDataSource, NumData, NumVal
import numpy as np

excel_file = 'treatment_copy.xlsx'#input("Please input excel file to be analyzed: ")
wb = xl.load_workbook(excel_file)
sheet = wb["Sheet2"]

chart1 = BarChart()
chart1.height = 10
chart1.width = 15
chart1.title = 'Example Title'

data = Reference(sheet,
            min_col=3,
            min_row=2,
            max_col=3,
            max_row =7)
cats = Reference(sheet,
            min_col=1,
            min_row=2,
            max_col=2,
            max_row =7)


chart1.add_data(data)
chart1.set_categories(cats)
sheet.add_chart(chart1, "A45")

wb.save(excel_file)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What you have to do with any advanced charting functions is inspect the XML generated by Excel. You can then usually workout what you need to do in openpyxl which implements the schema almost 1:1. Discussion of details is easiset on the openpyxl mailing list.